# Hamachi: Cannot ping my or anyone else's IP

Tags: firewall, network, ping

I have been using [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/) successfully on my computer for years, but recently, it's been acting up. I cannot ping anyone else on Hamachi. If I click them and hit ping, I just get:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
```

And so on until I stop it. I looked into this issue and found some troubleshooting instructions. It said to `ping 127.0.0.1`. This was successful.

It then said to ping my own 25.x.x.x hamachi IP. This resulted in the same request timeout error.

The troubleshooting guide said that this means my firewall settings are somehow blocking connectivity. This issue is that I don't have a firewall enabled:

[image]

Furthermore I haven't changed any network settings since it was working.

Some other information that may or may not be relevant: I'm on Mac OS 10.12.6, and I'm using Hamachi version 2.1.0.821.

What could the issue be? And how can I resolve it?

Let me know if there is any other relevant information I can add.

EDIT: It is specifically an issue on my end, as my friends tested it and they can ping other people's Hamachi IPs successfully, but not mine. When they try to ping me, they get the same request timeout error.

Comment: **PM B.Johnson** was in a bad mood yesterday evening and gave **Her Majesty's Principal Secretary of State for Defence** the order to stealthen [25.0.0.0/8](https://bgpview.io/prefix/25.0.0.0/8). Every dust grain in the **MOD** requires its own IP-address now.

Comment: @klanomath I'm not in the UK though, I'm in the US. Does this still affect me?

Comment: Sure, this is the Internet! But I'm not totally joking: Hamachi/LogMeIn [squatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogMeIn_Hamachi#Addressing) 25.0.0.0/8 which is assigned to the UK Ministry of Defence. In my opinion either the mediation server is down or it's some strange IP-address collision.

Comment: @klanomath The one issue with that theory is that my friends tested it and they could ping other people successfully, but not me. That should probably go in the post, I will edit it in.

Comment: I don't really know how Hamachi works (OK, I probably know how to use it  - similar as a VPN-client - and some fundamental tech background). Do you get a new IP after logging out & in again there? Or do you get a fixed IP in the 25.0.0.0/8 range?

Comment: Any software that might be monitoring network ?

Comment: @klanomath It doesn't change every time I log out and in. It gives me an IP in the 25.0.0.0 range that does change occasionally. Once every few months or so. I'm not really sure what triggers it.

Comment: @ankii Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @RothX Does Hamachi log anything somewhere on your Mac? IP-changes/diagnostics etc.. Can you initiate an IP-reset (in the 25.0.0.0/8 range) from your side?

Comment: @RothX You may also post the IP here (since it's defunct on your side). Then we may be able to trace the IP (e.g. to a surveillance camera in the left eye of the Gurkha Soldier Statue at [Horse Guard Avenue](https://www.google.com/maps/place/51%C2%B030'14.4%22N+0%C2%B007'29.6%22W/@51.5048629,-0.1250145,106m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.504!4d-0.1249?hl=en)).